# Identify each of the sets of points given below and make your chart

Tags: complex-numbers

a. | − | + | + 2| = 3

b. | − 2| = 2| + 2|

How do I find the set of complex points satisfying the previous equations?

Answer (score 0):

The first is an ellipse by definition.

The second is the Apollonian circle for a triangle:

Let $z=x+yi$, where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Thus,
$$(x-2)^2+y^2=4(x^2+(y+2)^2)$$ or
$$x^2+y^2+\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{16}{3}y=-4$$ or
$$\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{8}{3}\right)^2=\frac{32}{9}$$

Comment: But how do I find out the points that satisfy this?

Comment: For the first you can get the equation after rotation by an ugly angle. The second is easy. I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:first put $z=x+iy$  then 
$$| − | + | + 2| = 3\\
|x+iy − | + |x+iy + 2| = 3\\|x+i(y-1)|+|(x+2)+iy|=3\\\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=3$$then  to the power of two ,but before $$\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}=-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+3\\(\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}=-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+3)^2\\
x^2+y^2-2y+1=x^2+4x+4+y^2+9-6\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$$simplify 
$$-2y+1=4x+4+9-6\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}\\6\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=4x+2y+12\\3\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=2x+y+6$$again to the power of two 
$$(3\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=2x+y+6)^2\\9(x+2)^2+9y^2=4x^2+y^2+36+4xy+24x+12y\\
9x^2+36x+36+9y^2=4x^2+y^2+36+4xy+24x+12y$$can you go on  ?
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kyef5nzk17

Comment: How do I get a set with this result?

Comment: $$|z-z_1|+|z-z_2|=k$$ is an ellipse . you can simplify and take into standard form of conic section.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. Sorry